# Linux - Getting ELF Data for Linux Utility

Tags: linux, elf

I'm trying to get ELF data (Section Header Table, SHT) for Linux system utilities.

I've noticed that I can get this info for my own programs when those were compiled such that objects (`.o`) file is created. I also managed to get SHT for `bash` via `readelf`, by typing:

```
readelf -l /bin/bash
```

However, it doesn't work for some utilities, like gunzip. For instance, I want to type-in something like:

```
readelf -S tar -czvf large_file.tar.gz large_file.dat
```

and get a set of execution attributes, like the ones in the below picture:

[image: SHT]

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Alexander.

Comment: Keep in mind that `gunzip` is a shell script in Ubuntu 17.10, so `readelf` won't work. Besides that, always try provide enough details to allow reproducing your exact problem. In this case, that would be: what is your operating system version and version of gunzip? In this case,  I don't know what is going on immediately, but try to play around with "strip" or debug data options of GCC and a minimal hello world. Finally, if you are using an open source OS, see what options your distro gives to GCC to compile gunzip to find out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, Ciro. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The manpage for `readelf` shows that it expects to receive the path to an ELF binary file as its argument, not an entire command like `tar -czvf large_file.tar.gz large_file.dat`.

To find ELF data for `tar`, do this:

```
which tar
readelf -S <path to tar binary>
```

On my system, the path to `tar` is simply `/bin/tar`.